# KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access Spark Streaming Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to join 2 different streams coming from apache Kafka (2 different topics) in Apache Spark Streaming on a cluster of machines.
The messages I send are string "formatted" as a csv string (comma separated).

This is the Spark code:

```
// Create the context with a 5 second batch size
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkScript").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true").set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", "3").setMaster("spark://0.0.0.0:7077")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(3))

case class Location(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, name: String)

case class Datas1(location : Location, timestamp : String, measurement : Double, unit: String, accuracy : Double, elem: String, elems: String, elemss: String)
case class Sensors1(sensor_name: String, start_date: String, end_date: String, data1: Datas1)    


val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
    "bootstrap.servers" -> "0.0.0.0:9092",
    "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer].getCanonicalName,
    "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer].getCanonicalName,
    "group.id" -> "test_luca",
    "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
    "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)

val topics1 = Array("topics1")

val stream1 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topics1, kafkaParams))
val s1pre = stream1.map(record => record.value.split(",").map(_.trim))
val s1 = s1pre.map(x =>  Sensors1(x.apply(6), "2016-03-01T00:00:00.000", "2018-09-01T00:00:00.000", Datas1(Location(x.apply(1).toDouble,x.apply(2).toDouble, ""), x.apply(0) ,x.apply(3).toDouble,x.apply(5),x.apply(4).toDouble,x.apply(7),x.apply(8),x.apply(9)))

val topics2 = Array("topics2")

val stream2 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topics2, kafkaParams))
val s2pre = stream2.map(record => record.value.split(",").map(_.trim))
val s2 = s2pre.map(x =>  Sensors1(x.apply(6), "2016-03-01T00:00:00.000", "2018-09-01T00:00:00.000", Datas1(Location(x.apply(1).toDouble,x.apply(2).toDouble, ""), x.apply(0) ,x.apply(3).toDouble,x.apply(5),x.apply(4).toDouble,x.apply(7),x.apply(8),x.apply(9)))


val j1s1 = s1.map(x => (x.data1.timestamp, (x)))
val j1s2 = s2.map(x => (x.data1.timestamp, (x)))
val j1s1win = j1s1.window(Seconds(3), Seconds(6))
val j1s2win = j1s2.window(Seconds(3), Seconds(6))
val j1pre = j1s1win.join(j1s2win)
case class Sensorj1(sensor_name: String, start_date: String, end_date: String)
val j1 = j1pre.map { r => new Sensorj1("j1", r._2._1.start_date, r._2._1.end_date)}
j1.print()
```

The problem I have is "KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access". 
After reading different posts I changed my code by adding `cache()` at the end of the KafkaConsumer (val stream1 and val stream2).
After that I do not have the same error but I have a serialization error on the string I try to map.

I do not understand and I do not have any idea on how to fix this problem.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
LF